# How to share - a blog's title, picture and short content from its link - in social media with the link to the blog?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a blog page where the each blogs are accessed by

```
http://<domain>.com/blogs?id=2344
```

If I copy this link and paste in social media platforms like LinkedIn, Facebook etc, I want to show the thumbnail, title and short description along with the post. The post div look like below

```
<div id="10002" name="div_post" class="post row" categoryname="Business"><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row post-header"><div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-xs-5 hidden-xs text-center pull-right bbrown"><div class="profile_pic"><div class="pretty_alias" id="avatar_10001"><h3 class="hiddens to_curve top"><span class="char char0"><div>k</div></span><span class="char char1"><div>g</div></span><span class="char char2"><div>r</div></span><span class="char char3"><div>l</div></span><span class="char char4"><div>a</div></span></h3><h3 class="bottom"><span class="id id0"><div>3</div></span><span class="id id1"><div>8</div></span><span class="id id2"><div>3</div></span><span class="id id3"><div>7</div></span><span class="id id4"><div>5</div></span><span class="id id5"><div>6</div></span></h3></div></div><span class="col-sm-12 text-center bbrown"><h6 class="text-capitalize usertitle"></h6></span></div><h1 style="margin-left:0.5em">Post heading</h1><h6 style="margin-left:1.6em" class="poststamp">March 10th 2016</h6></div></div><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row post-content"><div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-12"><div class="pull-right" style="width:50%;margin-left:20px;"><div class="row"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://thissite.com/post_img_10002_1.jpg"></div></div>Content </a><br> </div></div></div><div class="container"><div class="row"><h6 style="margin-left:0.5em"> &nbsp;<span class="badge">Business</span></h6></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></span></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Other closely related blogs will be displayed below this blog. A very similar behaviour can be seen in LinkedIn pulse. The only difference is that we are using query string to fetch the post.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: for facebook read this https://web.facebook.com/notes/hyperarts-web-design/set-up-your-website-to-control-images-text-in-facebook-status-update-links/10150320031290844/?_rdr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: http://ogp.me/

An example of title, images, etc...

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Facebook Open Graph META Tags"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://blog.com/img/facebooklogo.png"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="John Smith Blog"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Facebook's Open Graph protocol allows for web developers to add description" />
```

You should probably change your template to serve these tags.

Comment: 1) How can i ensure the suggested meta tags class with the main website's meta tags?

Comment: 2) There are multiple blogs in the page (which is the case) and how would a blog gets linked to a specific meta tag? Put it the other way, how will social media platforms understand which meta tag to be used out of many available in the page?

Comment: You should have one set of metas per blog page. If you share the link for http://<domain>.com/blogs?id=2344 that blog should have its own metas

Comment: What I have learned is the social media platform fetches the og from the link that we use and fetches the information to display. The key was to populate og tab dynamically for blog ids. In a way your answer helped